# Share an object application-wide in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, application-variables

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 web application with C# and Razor.

Through a form in a View I get the `Context.User.Identity.Name` submitted to an action method in a **Controller A**.

I would like to have available this variable application-wide (between multiple controllers). 
Now I am just able to assign it to a global variable **_UserName** within the **Controller A**, but of course it is not available in **Controller B**.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing this in any controller, you should use HttpContext.User.Identity in your controller methods - it will be available there. No need to store in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Create a parent controller from which all your controllers inherit from and set the variable there. You could do a number of things with it from there--wrap it in a view model, put some user details into the ViewBag, etc

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    // create your own User class with as many properties as you need
    protected User user { get; set; }

    public UserController()
    {
        user = // get user from db, wherever
    }
}
```

Then, just inherit from UserController

```
public class ControllerA : UserController
{
    public ActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        user.Property = 123;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into caching and possibly using the users session store this information.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866493/retrieving-and-caching-html-from-website-using-asp-net-mvc-3) question.

Comment: I really don't understand the quick downvoting of everyone on here sometimes. This is an answer that WOULD WORK. Might not be the most convenient for him, but who knows, maybe it is?